# procedures to calculate duration from startdate and enddate SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm creating a database for a school work and I'm having trouble with one thing I want to do.
I'm working on a real case, so I have the attributes **EndDate**, **StartDate**, and **Duration** in a relationship, and I have to create a trigger for the **Duration**. However, firstly I need to calculate it. It is a derivated attribute from **StartDate** and **EndDate**, but I don't know how to do that. 
I've been checking Procedures and Functions to do it (and I think it has to be a procedure so that the SQL calculates it whenever a tuple is inserted). I've been trying to use the `DATEDIFF`, but I really don't know how to do it with existing attributes. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Show us how you tried to use DATEDIFF and what was wrong with the result.

Comment: You can create a trigger on table having attributes `EndDate`, `StartDate`. You can put the trigger on before update and in that you can calculate the value of `Duration` using `datediff` (in days) or `timediff` (in hour::min::sec).

`new.duration = datediff(new.end_date, new.start_date)`

Comment: For the record, this is the first time that I'm using code to do something, so I'm very naive. I've been trying to use it with the attributes EndDate and StartDate:  DATEDIFF(Days, StartDate, EndDate) but SQL says that I can't use that. I've tried with specific examples and nothing. This is what I have now: DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE spCalculateDuration ()
Begin
 Select floor(datediff(day, +5, '05-06-2017')) AS Duration
    From UserObjective AS UO
    ORDER BY Duracao DESC;
END $$

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. And you can't write stored procedures in "SQL" - you need some kind of procedural language which is highly product specific.

Comment: I'm using MySQL... Whenever I used "SQL" I meant MySQL. Sorry for the mistake and thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look deeper on DecoderReloaded's comment on your post.

You can do a INSTEAD OF [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) to persist in a column when the query started, and a AFTER trigger to persist in another column when it ended.

Example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerInsteadOf  
ON YourTable  
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE  
 --You should repeat your queries here (as always needed with INSTEAD OF triggers) and set the datetime column value for the start time.
GO  

CREATE TRIGGER TriggerAfter  
ON YourTable  
AFTER INSERT  
 --Don't need to repeat your queries here (as always happen with AFTER triggers) and set the datetime column value for the end time, or a DATEDIFF() to obtain the timespan.
GO
```

Watch out for multiples updates and you maybe should consider DELETEs commands, too, depending on what you want to achieve.

This isn't the ultimate idea, but it will work well if implemented. Good luck.